# extracting characters from python string using variable index

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'm trying to split a string of letters and numbers into a list of tuples like this:

[(37, 'M'), (1, 'I'), (5, 'M'), (1, 'D'), (25, 'M'), (33, 'S')]

This is what is kind of working, but when I try to get print "37" (print(cigar[d:pos])) it does not print the entire string, only 3.

```
#iterate through cigar sequence
print(cigar)
#count position in cigar sequence
pos=0
#count position of last key
d=0

splitCigar=[]

for char in cigar:
    
    #print(cigar[pos])
    if char.isalpha() == False:
        print("first for-loop")
        print(cigar[d])
        print(cigar[pos])
        print(cigar[d:pos])
        num=(cigar[d:pos])
        pos+=1

    if char.isalpha() == True:
        print("second for-loop")
        splitCigar.append((num,char))
        pos+=1
        d=pos   
    
print(splitCigar)
```

The output of this code:

```
37M1I5M1D25M33S
first for-loop
3
3

first for-loop
3
7
3
second for-loop

<and so on...>

second for-loop
[('3', 'M'), ('', 'I'), ('', 'M'), ('', 'D'), ('2', 'M'), ('3', 'S')]
```

Comment: can you clarify your input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using regexp:

```py
import re
cigar = "37M1I5M1D25M33S"

digits = re.findall('[0-9]+', cigar)
chars = re.findall('[A-Z]+', cigar)

results = list(zip(digits, chars))
```

Everything printed so you can see what it does:

```py
>>> print(digits)
['37', '1', '5', '1', '25', '33']
>>> print(chars)
['M', 'I', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'S']
>>> print(results)
[('37', 'M'), ('1', 'I'), ('5', 'M'), ('1', 'D'), ('25', 'M'), ('33', 'S')]
```

I hope this "functional" approach suits you

Comment: Yes, thank you! Is there any way to convert the digits to integers in the final results?

Comment: Sure things! You can do `digits = [int(digit) for digit in digits]` to convert them before zipping

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing library makes writing parsers more maintainable and readable.
If the format of the data changes, you can modify the parser without too much effort.

```py
import pyparsing as pp


def make_grammar():
    # Number consists of several digits
    num = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName("Num")
    # Convert the num to int
    num = num.setParseAction(
        pp.pyparsing_common.convertToInteger)
    # 1 letter
    letter = pp.Word(pp.alphas, exact=1)\
        .setName("Letter")
    # 1 num followed by letter with possibly
    # some spaces in between
    package = pp.Group(num + letter)
    # 1 or more packages
    grammar = pp.OneOrMore(package)
    return grammar


def main():
    x = "37M1I5M1D25M33S"
    g = make_grammar()
    result = g.parseString(x, parseAll=True)
    print(result)
    # [[37, 'M'], [1, 'I'], [5, 'M'], 
    #  [1, 'D'], [25, 'M'], [33, 'S']]
    # If you really want tuples:
    print([tuple(r) for r in result])


main()
```

Comment: Nice example. Note that pyparsing now has the Char class that you can use in place of `Word(exact=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```py
inp = '37M1I5M1D25M33S'
e = [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(inp, key=lambda l: l.isdigit())]
print(e)
```

This will give you-

```py
['37', 'M', '1', 'I', '5', 'M', '1', 'D', '25', 'M', '33', 'S']
```

Basically, `groupby` collects all consecutive elements that satisfy the `key` function (`.isdigit`) into groups, each of those groups is turned into a string using `''.join`

Now, all you have to do is zip them together-

```py
res = list(zip(e[::2], e[1::2]))
print(res)
```

That will give you

```py
[('37', 'M'), ('1', 'I'), ('5', 'M'), ('1', 'D'), ('25', 'M'), ('33', 'S')]
```

If you want numericals instead of string representation of numbers, that's also super simple-

```py
res = list(map(lambda l: (int(l[0]), l[1]), res))
```

Which yields

```py
[(37, 'M'), (1, 'I'), (5, 'M'), (1, 'D'), (25, 'M'), (33, 'S')]
```

I'd say this is a pretty pythonic solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attain the desired output as follows:

```
cigar= '37M1I5M1D25M33S'

splitCigar=[]
t=[]
num=''
for char in cigar:
    if char.isalpha()==False:
        num+= char
    else:
        t.append(num)
        num=''
        t.append(char)
        
        splitCigar.append(tuple(t))
        t=[]
print(splitCigar)
```

Output:
[('37', 'M'), ('1', 'I'), ('5', 'M'), ('1', 'D'), ('25', 'M'), ('33', 'S')]